# waves.conf bug while upgrading to Waves 1.0.2

Tags: wavesplatform, ride

We've got the following question about Waves node configuration:

> I’ve updated my secondary node from v1.0.1 to v1.0.2 and it’s doing a
>   state rebuild. I just downloaded the deb, installed it, then restarted
>   waves and finally found the importer messages in the log. Has anyone
>   else reported this behaviour or have I made some mistake I’m not
>   realising?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please assure that in your `/etc/waves/waves.conf` the `waves.directory` points to the correct directory.

If this option doesn't exist in the config, default directory `/var/lib/waves` and `/var/lib/waves-testnet` will be used for Mainnet and Testnet, respectively.

It's stated in the Waves Node configuration docs:
https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-node/node-configuration.html